# CSS media query not working correctly

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I not understand why this media query not working.

I would like to apply some code if screen width is `480px`.
In this case i'm using:

```
@media screen  and (width: 480px) {
}
```

but nothing happens. I tried work around with

```
@media screen  and (max-width: 481px) and  (min-width: 479px) {
```

still not working 
it works only with `@media screen  and (max-width: 481px)` but how is other end?

Comment: What are you putting within the media css query?

Comment: some css code for small screen mobile devices

Comment: it works with `@media screen  and (max-width: 480px)` but works with less then `480` but i don't want it. i need only `480`

Answer (score 1):

Just try this, you specify screen in your rule, if you try to access with another it doesn't work :

EDIT : The snippet got padding and margin so test with 507px or try on my fiddle at 480px: http://jsfiddle.net/46u4kggq/1

Dont try it with chrome responsive tool because there is no viewport on the snippet

```css
body{
  background: black;
}

@media (width: 480px){
  body{
    background: yellow;
   }
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: It's work, background is yellow when width is exactly 480px

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman It is not providing an answer to question. It's not working. You should at least try your solution before posting.

Comment: Are you serious guys ?! Just open snippet in full width and resize your window at 480px

Comment: @Cyril, do we look like idiots.. I done exactly what you're saying and sized it to 480px it doesn't work.

Comment: @Option what is your browser ?

Comment: @Cyril, Chrome, yet I went to the extent of trying Safari as well.

Comment: @Option It's work's fine on chrome and firefox for me... just it's hard to go 480px exactly... but when you are at 480px it's work's fine for me

Comment: Chrome has a responsive mobile section buiit in you can simply type the pixel size. Anyhow, I'm not going to sit here and dispute it. It's not working..

Comment: @Option I just test it with chrome responsive tool but there is no viewport on the snippet so at 480px it's doesn't work, juste resize window direclty and dont use chrome responsive tool, test on my fiddle and try 507 width because the snippet got padding and margin

Comment: @Option Works fine for me seems like chromes responsive tool isn't perfect and doesn't actually change the `body` width. if you open the snippet up and set the width to `120px` in chromes responsive tool the `body` element will be `480px` and as if magic it will turn yellow

Answer (score 0):

try using jquery for this, In css media query you cannot target exact width only max-width and min-width are possible.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function checkWidth() 
 { 
   var windowSize = $(window).width(); 
   if (windowSize == 480) 
   { 
        console.log("screen width is equal t0 480"); 
    }
 } // Execute on load checkWidth(); // Bind event listener 
 $(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

});

Comment: function checkWidth() {
        var windowSize = $(window).width();

        if (windowSize == 480) {
            console.log("screen width is equal t0 480");
        }
        
    }

    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

Comment: add the code to your answer not in the comments section.

Comment: IT will not work in css , your css code is not working